# CSS: How to display hidden class

Tags: css, class, hidden

I'm trying to display with css the navigation buttons that are located inside my jquery rotating banner.

Which are:

```
<a class="ls-nav-prev" href="#"></a>
<a class="ls-nav-next" href="#"></a>
```

For some reason I can't show them, I've tried changing their position, setting a z-index, adding a background-image and color.

**Here's the website:**

http://npmaudiovisual.com/esde/

**This is what I have:**

[image]

**This is what I should have (buttons on corners)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need some room for them on the page or they will be hidden.
Also there is no text or image within the DIVs.

```
a class="ls-nav-prev" href="#" style="float:left;">Prev</a>
<a class="ls-nav-next" href="#" style="float:right;">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your CSS for the following:

```
<a class="ls-nav-prev" href="#"></a>
<a class="ls-nav-next" href="#"></a>
```

in **layerslider.css** just has

```
.ls-nav-prev,
.ls-nav-next {
    outline: none;
}
```

This does not generate any image or content. How are you testing it?

**Secondly, separate the classes and add positioning properties:**

```
.ls-nav-prev {
    left:-35px
    position:absolute
    top:200px
}

.ls-nav-next {
    left:935px
    position:absolute
    top:200px
}
```

You can play around with the `left` and `top` property values to suit your needs.